# Finding similar matrix without performing matrix inversion

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

suppose that we have matrix $\textbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$. I would like to find a similar matrix $\textbf{B}$, i.e. $\textbf{A} \sim \textbf{B}$, without performing any matrix inversions. I know that for some $\textbf{S}$, we would have $\textbf{B}=\textbf{S}^{-1}\textbf{A}\textbf{S} \sim \textbf{A}$, but I want to avoid inversion. Thanks!

Comment: Given two matrix, to check if they are similar is quite easy. But given a matrix, to find a similar one I am not sure

Comment: Swap rows 1 and 2, then columns 1 and 2. This uses a (permutation) matrix that equals its inverse.